# Using ideas from HashEmbeddings with sklearn's HashingVectorizer

Tags: python, text, hash, scikit-learn, nlp

[Svenstrup et. al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03933) propose an interesting way to handle hash collisions in hashing vectorizers: Use 2 different hashing functions, and concatenate their results before modeling.

They claim that the combination of multiple hash functions approximates a single hash function with much larger range (see section 4 of the paper).

I'd like to try this out with some text data I'm working with in sklearn.  The idea would be to run the [HashingVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) twice, with a different hash function each time, and then concatenate the results as an input to my model.

How might I do with with sklearn?  There's not an option to change the hash function used, but maybe could modify the vectorizer somehow?

Or maybe there's a way I could achieve this with [SparseRandomProjection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.random_projection.SparseRandomProjection.html) ?

Comment: Great question. Thanks for linking to the paper. (I am also working on large text data and was trying something similar). `HashingVectorizer` calls [`FeatureHasher`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html) internally which in turn uses the `Murmurhash3` function. If we can change that, then I think this can be done with [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html). Can you describe more about your use-case (maybe an example of what you want)?

Comment: I found the implementation of the referenced paper here: https://github.com/dsv77/hashembedding/blob/master/HashEmbedding/example.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HashingVectorizer in scikit-learn already includes a mechanism  to mitigate hash collisions with [`alternate_sign=True`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) option. This adds a random sign during token summation which improves the preservation of distances in the hashed space (see [scikit-learn#7513](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7513#issuecomment-252322348) for more details).

By using `N` hash functions and concatenating the output, one would increase both `n_features` and  the number of non null terms (`nnz`) in the resulting sparse matrix  by `N`. In other words each token will now be represented as N elements. This is quite wastful memory wise. In addition, since the run time for  sparse array computations is directly dependent on `nnz` (and less so on `n_features`) this will have a much larger negative performance impact than only increasing `n_features`. I'm not sure that such approach is very useful in practice.

If you nevertheless want to implement such vectorizer, below are a few comments.

- because `FeatureHasher` is implemented in Cython, it is difficult to modify its functionality from Python without editing/re-compiling the code.
- writing a quick pure-python implemnteation of HashingVectorizer could be one way to do it.
- otherwise, there is a somewhat experimental re-implementation of HashingVectorizer in the [text-vectorize](https://github.com/rth/text-vectorize) package. Because it is written in Rust (with Python binding), other hash functions are easily accessible and [can potentially be added](https://github.com/rth/text-vectorize/issues/10).